History of the development of graph theory
I’m looking for a book or reference on the history of the development of graph theory. I would especially appreciate something with both technical and historical details. An example of something like this is Gregory H. Moore’s book “Zermelo’s Axiom of Choice: Its Origins, Development, and Influence”.
Most writings on graph theory history that I’ve found are very bare bones on the early history, mentioning Euler and then skipping without much detail to the early/mid-20th century — but maybe I just haven’t looked hard enough yet.

You should expect a skip to at least the mid-19th century after Euler. Euler was doing graph theory in the sense of "solving a graph-theoretic problem" but not in the sense of "modeling with graphs". The language of graph theory didn't exist until the late 1800s, and I think serious grappling with the concepts of graph theory began only a bit earlier than that, with the map four-coloring problem. Before then, we can only give credit to a few people for being ahead of their time, like Euler (or, say, the 9th century poet Rudrata, for the earliest example of a Hamiltonian cycle).

@MishaLavrov I do expect a big jump — just not as big as Euler to the computer age :) but I do appreciate your comment to make sure my expectations are realistic!

Biggs, N., Lloyd, E. K., & Wilson, R. J. (1986). Graph Theory, 1736-1936. Oxford University Press.
Please note, however, that this book is by no means an exhaustive treatment.

Thank you, I think that’s exactly what I’m looking for! :)
